# Cannot type using onboard

Tags: keyboard

Having problems typing with Onboard, I can use the other one, at a much slower speed. Yet I can " Type Symbols " on Onboard Keypad... I do not understand ( I am New to the Computer ), Please Help :(

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by that you can type symbols and you can't type letters as it is on the onboard, it looks like your language packs are installed with missing libraries.

to fix this:

1. go to system settings.language support
2. click on install/remove languages (a list if installed languages will pop-up)
3. see if the language you are using is checked or not (if not)...
4. check it and the system will starting updating the language pack.
5. wait until the update finish and click apply system-wide.

Try to run onboard and ckeck if it is now working.